# Accessing attribute from parent class inside child class

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, inheritance

When I access an attribute from the parent class via the child class like this all works fine:

```
class A():
    a=1
    b=2

class B(A):
    c=3

d=B.a+B.b+B.c
print d
```

But if I try to access an attribute from the parent class inside the child class like this, it doesn't work:

```
class A():
    a=1
    b=2

class B(A):
    c=3
    d=a+b+c
    print d
```

I receive the error: `name 'a' is not defined`

Let assume that I have many equation like d=a+b+c (but more complicated) and I can't edit them - I have to call in class B "a" as "a", not "self.a" or "something.a". But I can, before equations, do A.a=a. But it is not the smartest way to reload all variables manually. I want to bypass it using inheritance. Is it possible or i should do all manually? Or maybe it is 3th route in this code?

Comment: `print d` will obviously fail because `d` is not defined. Besides this is not the recommended way to do inheritance, see @Jake77's answer

Comment: The inherited class attributes aren't available until after the definition completes, unless you access them directly at e.g. `A.a`

Comment: To bring the discussion back up to the question - could you edit to show a more useful example of *what you're trying to achieve?* This is likely an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: We don't normally use Python classes in the way that you're attempting to do. You should be creating  _instances_ of your classes, and manipulating the instance attributes inside the instances' methods. Doing arithmetic directly on class attributes outside a method definition looks plain weird, and although it _is_ a permissible way to initialize class attributes, it's certainly _not_ recommended as a general calculation technique.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - i edited question. I hope now it is more clear. Sorry if i did too long discussion but people ignored that i can't use prefix inside equations. I know it may look sily but i did it this way before and i don't want throw all my work.

Comment: @Karls but you still haven't actually explained *why*, or what is going on more broadly. Please give a [mcve] that **actually shows what's happening**. *"people ignored that i can't use prefix inside equations"* - because that doesn't make sense, what is the *actual reason* why not? *"I have to call in class B "a" as "a""* - that **cannot work** within the definition, as my answer explains, so *something* will have to give.

Comment: I showed the reason several times - **too many equations to add manualy "slef", or prefix in ever place**. What it will help if i will copy and past 100 or more equations? It will just do mess here.

Comment: There's probably a simple way to do what you want that doesn't require you to clutter your equations with prefixes. But it's hard for us to help you when you still haven't explained what you're _really_ trying to do. We don't need (or want) to see 100 equations, but a simple, minimal, example would be helpful: it'd show us what you're trying to achieve, and it would make it easier for us to explain what's wrong with your current approach.

Comment: Ok, i edited question.

Comment: Your new code _still_ doesn't help us to understand what you're _really_ trying to do. And it doesn't show us how you're attempting to use classes, so we can't explain what's wrong with you're current approach. I suspect that you probably don't even need classes, but it's hard to tell from the information you have supplied so far.

Answer (score 9):

During the class definition, none of the inherited attributes are available:

```
>>> class Super(object):
    class_attribute = None
    def instance_method(self):
        pass


>>> class Sub(Super):
    foo = class_attribute



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    class Sub(Super):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 2, in Sub
    foo = class_attribute
NameError: name 'class_attribute' is not defined
>>> class Sub(Super):
    foo = instance_method



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    class Sub(Super):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 2, in Sub
    foo = instance_method
NameError: name 'instance_method' is not defined
```

You can't even access them using `super`, as the name of the subclass isn't defined within the definition block*:

```
>>> class Sub(Super):
    foo = super(Sub).instance_method



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    class Sub(Super):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 2, in Sub
    foo = super(Sub).instance_method
NameError: name 'Sub' is not defined
```

The *only way* to access the inherited attributes at definition time is to do so explicitly, using the name of the superclass:

```
>>> class Sub(Super):
    foo = Super.class_attribute


>>> Sub.foo is Super.class_attribute
True
```

Alternatively you can access them within class or instance methods, but then you need to use the appropriate prefix of the class (conventionally `cls`) or instance (conventionally `self`) parameter.

---

* for anyone thinking *"ah, but in 3.x you don't need arguments to `super`"*:

```
>>> class Sub(Super):
    foo = super().instance_method


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    class Sub(Super):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 2, in Sub
    foo = super().instance_method
RuntimeError: super(): no arguments
```

That's only true inside instance/class methods!

Comment: The fact that you call your parent class "Super" has been very confusing for me...

Answer (score 4):

I may be wrong on this, but are you sure you don't want rather this?

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        self.c = 3

    @property
    def d(self):
        return self.a + self.b + self.c

BB = B()
print BB.d
```

or, as jonrsharpe pointed out:

```
class A():
    a=1
    b=2

class B(A):
    c=3
    d=A.a+A.b+c

print B.d
```

Comment: I corrected the position of print, it was only my mistake. But it doesn't matter, print is only to be sure it calculate correctly but so far it doesn't calculate in any way. I know i can access it with prefix A.*, but in my real, more complicated code i can not use it or i will be forced to rewrite aboute 150-200 quitation, manually adding prefix. Is it any option to fix it without adding self or any other prefix to equitation?

Comment: @Karls no, there isn't; you need to be explicit about where you want the value to come from.

Comment: as I understand you neither call the __init__ of the base class in the child, nor create instances of your classes. May I ask why?

Comment: @Jake77 - i want to make my example as simple as possible. It is quite strange for me that inheriting works only after after the definition completes. So in my case the inheriting is useless? I had to use prefix anyway?

Comment: No it isn't. But I _think_ you define class variables. If you had instances, by calling the __init__ of the base you make all attributes of the base accessible in the child - that is the reason for my answer at first.

Comment: @Karls that's related to the way class attributes are defined - the class definition is a separate namespace, and you don't get access to inherited names during the definition itself (as they're added afterwards). You can access them inside class/instance methods, as they (logically) cannot run until after definition time, but you then have to access them via `cls`/`self`.

Comment: Ok but i still have to add "self" prefix to all variables and as i mentioned before i can't. So how to bypass it?

Comment: @Karls *"as i mentioned before i can't"* - then you're SOL. *"So how to bypass it?"* - you can't.

Comment: You cant. It is not the prefix, but the dot. The dot operator says to take the attribute after the dot from the object with the name before it. You can't bypass it in definition.

Comment: Ok so i can't use inheriting to access the variables (unless i want to rewrite manually a lot of equitation) in the way i need. I have to look for another solution. Maybe i could reload all variables as local like "A.x = x" in the B class. Maybe do you know any fast way to reload all variables from one class to another? Or do you have simpler idea to solve the problem?

Comment: I don't know what the "way you need" is, but in the long run you are definitely better to follow the way python was meant to use then to stick with a solution that brought you to a dead end.

Comment: Well if i have to manualy rewrite more then 100 equations, risking the mistakes and bad results i will try baypass it in safe way. "The way i need" is to call value from class A in class B without dot or prefix. I can load all variables like "A.x = x" but i can't change anything in complicated equations. So i have to call inside class B variable "x" as "x" not "something.x" inside equations (in other situation in class i can use self or prefix)

Comment: @Karls but you have to rewrite them anyway, because what you're doing now won't work. Again, please edit the question with a more representative example, and I suggest continuing this discussion (if necessary) under the question rather than an answer