# Using inherited variables in subclass's method on their default arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, inheritance

I would like to use an inherited variable as one of the **default** argument to a derived class's method. I want to do something that looks like the following :

```
class BaseFoo:
  _inherited = 'someval'

class Foo(BaseFoo):
  def dosomething( bar = _inherited ):
    print( bar ) # should print someval if we call dosomething()
```

I have tried using super()._inherited. But since super() needs an instance, putting it as a default arg will raise a RunTimeError: super() no arguments

I have also tried using self._inherited. But it returns a NameError, self not defined. I know that I can access _inherited within a function with either self or super(). But how do I do it on the while defining some default args ?

Edit :
I am aware on how to access inherited attributes in subclasses. But This question focuses on using them as default arguments. For those looking on accessing the attributes may refer to [Accessing attribute from parent class inside child class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346389/accessing-attribute-from-parent-class-inside-child-class)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing attribute from parent class inside child class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346389/accessing-attribute-from-parent-class-inside-child-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the base directly:

```
class BaseFoo:
  _inherited = 'someval'

class Foo(BaseFoo):
  def dosomething(self,bar=BaseFoo._inherited ):
    print( bar ) # should print someval if we call dosomething()
```

Output:

```
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.dosomething()
someval
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't really get the *inherited* property in the function argument because `self` isn't defined there. You *can* get the class property off the parent which [@MarkTolonen shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56250421/3874623). This might be what you want, but it's not the same thing.

Consider:

```
class BaseFoo:
    _inherited = 'someval'

class Foo(BaseFoo):
    def someAction(self):
        self._inherited = "other"
    def dosomething(self,bar=BaseFoo._inherited ):
        print( bar, self._inherited ) # should print someval if we call dosomething()

f = Foo()
f.someAction()  # changes f._inherited to "other"
f.dosomething() # what should be printed? self._inherited or bar?
# prints someval other
```

If the answer is still `someval` then this does what you need, but if you are hoping that the answer is `other`, then this doesn't work. You will need to actually set the value in the function body using the pattern that sets the default to `None` and checks:

```
class BaseFoo:
    _inherited = 'someval'

class Foo(BaseFoo):
    def someAction(self):
        self._inherited = "other"
    def dosomething(self,bar=None):
        if bar is None:
            bar = self._inherited
        print( bar, self._inherited ) 

f = Foo()
f.someAction()
f.dosomething()
# prints other other
```