# Python - access parent's class attribute from child's class method

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, inheritance

i'm stuck at this poin in my code where i need a method of a child class to use an attribute of the parent's class.

Here are the classes:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, section):
        self.section = section

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, section):
        super().__init__(section)
        self.name = self.get_name()

    def get_name(self):
        section = self.section
        name = "somestring_" + section
        return name
```

Now when executing the code below i get that `Child` does not have the `section` attribute:

```
child = Child('section')
print(child.name)
```

The expected output of the code should be: `somestring_section`.

I've tried calling the attribute directly with: `section = super().section` and doesn't work.

Also tried to call it like this: `section = Parent.section` and doesn't work.

Also tried to call it like this: `section = super(Child).section` and doesn't work.

Examples taken from this post here on stackoverflow: [Accessing attribute from parent class inside child class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346389/accessing-attribute-from-parent-class-inside-child-class)

Where i've made the error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you are running the code you've posted in the question? Runs fine by me - I get `somestring_section`

Comment: Works for me, too. You can inspect child's attributes like so: `dir(child)`, `section` is there.

Comment: I've tried again by creating a new .py file and by putting only those two classes and works. But in my code won't (didn't change anything, only removed one method that was using other modules).

I've manage to make it work by using this in the child class:
```
    def __init__(self, section):`
        self.section = section`
        super().__init__(self.section)
```

What could be the issue?